# How can we flatten the below structure using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

Sample JSON for testing: I loaded this into a `dataframe` using `pandas`: There are many keys but I only need `Id` and `Events` so I loaded this into a separate `dataframe`.

I need to iterate for each `id`(ex:abcd) and extract the events for that `id`. There are multiple `id`'s

I need this to be flattened into a single table or data frame with the below columns so that I can load it into an RDBMS

Some keys don't have values ex: `events[origin]` etc.

Appreciate your help.

Columns:

| id | description | time | origin_name | origin_code | remarks | destination_name | destination_code | invoice | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"abcd",
      "events":[
         {
            "description":"Liquidated",
            "time":"2020-12-18T12:00:00Z",
            "origin":{
               
            },
            "destination":{
               "name":" ",
               "code":"SAV"
            },
            "remarks":"L 99",
            "invoice":"pqr",
            "code":"LIQ"
         },
         {
            "description":"Customs Monthly Stmt Paid",
            "time":"2020-02-26T12:00:00Z",
            "origin":{
               "name":"abc, GA",
               "code":" "
            },
            "destination":{
               "name":"SAVANNAH, GA",
               "code":"SAV"
            },
            "remarks":"PM Stmt No 1720P0207Q",
            "invoice":"pqr",
            "code":"MSP"
         }
         ]
  },
  {
      "id":"xyz",
      "events":[
         {
            "description":"Liquidated",
            "time":"2020-12-18T12:00:00Z",
            "origin":{
               "name":"abc, GA",
               "code":" "
            },
            "destination":{
               
            },
            "remarks":"L 99",
            "invoice":" ",
            "code":"LIQ"
         },
         {
            "description":"Customs Monthly Stmt Paid",
            "time":"2020-02-26T12:00:00Z",
            "origin":{
               
            },
            "destination":{
               "name":"SAVANNAH, GA",
               "code":"SAV"
            },
            "remarks":"PM Stmt No 1720P0207Q",
            "invoice":" ",
            "code":"MSP"
         }
         ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to loop through `events` key then special handle `origin` and `destination` key:

```py
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

res = []

for d in data:
    for item in d['events']:
        temp_d = {}
        temp_d['id'] = d['id']

        for k, v in item.items():
            if k == 'origin' or k == 'destination':
                temp_d[f'{k}_name'] = v.get('name', np.nan)
                temp_d[f'{k}_code'] = v.get('code', np.nan)
            else:
                temp_d[k] = v

        res.append(temp_d)

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

```
print(df)

     id                description                  time origin_name origin_code destination_name destination_code                remarks invoice code
0  abcd                 Liquidated  2020-12-18T12:00:00Z     abc, GA                                           SAV                   L 99     pqr  LIQ
1  abcd  Customs Monthly Stmt Paid  2020-02-26T12:00:00Z         NaN         NaN     SAVANNAH, GA              SAV  PM Stmt No 1720P0207Q     pqr  MSP
2   xyz                 Liquidated  2020-12-18T12:00:00Z     abc, GA                          abc                                    L 99          LIQ
3   xyz  Customs Monthly Stmt Paid  2020-02-26T12:00:00Z         NaN         NaN     SAVANNAH, GA              SAV  PM Stmt No 1720P0207Q          MSP
```

Comment: Thanks but for some json files i don't have origin_name and origin_code ex: origin{ }

Comment: @virajpatel Example data?

Comment: Modified the sample json. Some keys have origin name and origin code same with destination_name and destination_code but for some keys these are empty ie they only have origin :{},destination:{}.  I've modified the source json file

Comment: @virajpatel I read your change log. You still have key `origin` and `destination` right? Have you really read and run my code?

Comment: Yes i ran the code and it is failing with the below error:  

[SQL Server]Invalid column name 'origin_name'. (207) (SQLExecute); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'origin_code'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'destination_name'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'destination_code'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: @virajpatel What is `SQLExecute`? How do you run my code? `data` in my code should be a dict parsed from your json.

Comment: Thanks It worked. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @virajpatel The idea is usage of `dict.get(key)`, if dict doesn't have `key`, it will return a default value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405.

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh. I did that. Appreciate your help.